# Delay Loading DLLs

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, delayed-execution

I am in desperate need of help, I need to manage an application dependency in Visual Studio. The application links to a DLL only on a specific version of windows, lets say Windows 7. and on other environments, the DLL should not be loaded. How will I be able to achieve that using DLL Delay Loading as this topic is completely new to me and there isn't any good references online for this particular matter.

Regards

Comment: Are you asking how delay-loading works, or how you can apply it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your project can specify that a dll it depends upon should but be loaded when needed, by specifying it in the Linker/Input/Delay Loaded DLLs field.  This setting can be different for different build configurations.

Comment: Thx for the reply man but can you giva an example or code snippet if its applicable :)

Comment: That's the point of delay loading: it's a configuration thing, not a code thing.

Comment: The wording appears wrong: When you say "The DLL you're depending upon should have been linked with the delay-load capacity", you're seem to be referring to the creation of that DLL from its constituent .obj's. The /DELAY flag is actually applied to the module that does the _importing_, not the _imported_ module. That's also the reason that you can delay-load Windows 2000 DLLs, which would have been built without this support.

Comment: @MSalters: You're right: the first option is for the dll to support _unloading_.  Corrected for that, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

MSDN has a pretty good description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx).

Basically what you are doing is setting the DLL in question to be in the delay load section.  It will then not load that DLL until you make a call to a function that is in that DLL.

From the above link:

> The Visual C++ linker now supports the delayed loading of DLLs. This
> relieves you of the need to use the Windows SDK functions LoadLibrary
> and GetProcAddress to implement DLL delayed loading.
>
> Before Visual C++ 6.0, the only way to load a DLL at run time was by
> using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress; the operating system would load
> the DLL when the executable or DLL using it was loaded.
>
> Beginning with Visual C++ 6.0, when statically linking with a DLL, the
> linker provides options to delay load the DLL until the program calls
> a function in that DLL.
>
> An application can delay load a DLL using the [/DELAYLOAD (Delay Load
> Import)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx) linker option with a helper function (default implementation
> provided by Visual C++). The helper function will load the DLL at run
> time by calling LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress for you.
>
> You should consider delay loading a DLL if:
>
> Your program may not call a function in the DLL.
>
> A function in the DLL may not get called until late in your program's
> execution.
>
> The delayed loading of a DLL can be specified during the build of
> either a .EXE or .DLL project. A .DLL project that delays the loading
> of one or more DLLs should not itself call a delay-loaded entry point
> in Dllmain.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using delay loading, have you considered using [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx) [loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx) with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`? This is likely to be simpler to use.

```
typedef void (WINAPI *PGNSI)(LPSYSTEM_INFO);

// Call GetNativeSystemInfo if supported or GetSystemInfo otherwise.

PGNSI pGNSI;
SYSTEM_INFO si;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(SYSTEM_INFO));

pGNSI = (PGNSI) GetProcAddress(
   GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), 
   "GetNativeSystemInfo");
if(NULL != pGNSI)
   pGNSI(&si);
else GetSystemInfo(&si);
```

Comment: How is it simpler to write code that can be automatically generated by the linker?

Comment: its fine if you only have 1 function you wish to call ... otherwise its a plain bad choice, imo.

Comment: -1 - the support for delay loading in the linker is specifically aimed at preventing you having to deal LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress()!

Comment: In the case of this question, (we assume) he knows that the DLL will be available on Windows 7 so he can detect the OS version before invoking a function call to the delayloaded DLL. However, it is sometimes the case that you can't know if a DLL is available on a system or what version (and thus what exported functions) are available. In those cases, using run-time dynamic linking is the appropriate albeit tedious solution. If you don't have some manner of detecting the presence of the DLL and required exported functions with 100% certainty, then delay loading may just be delay crashing.

Comment: I second xtofl and Bids.  So much more work to use runtime loading.